# Is it possible to bind to a property using reflection in WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, reflection, system.reflection

I'm writing code to generate a bunch of textboxes attached to property. Is there any way you can set the source to a property found using reflection, stored as `PropertyInfo`?

Code for going through the properties:

```
foreach(PropertyInfo prop in GetType().GetProperties())
{
    UI.Text ctrl = new UI.Text(prop.Name, prop.GetValue(this).ToString(), prop);
    sp.Children.Add(ctrl);
}
```

(Note: `UI.Text` is a custom control that contains the `TextBox`, and `sp` is a `StackPanel`)

Binding code:

```
Binding bind = new Binding() { Source = prop };
if (prop.CanWrite)
{
    TextBox.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, bind);
}
else
{
    TextBox.IsEnabled = false;
}
```

I currently get the error "Two-way binding requires Path or XPath" which usually occurs when trying to bind to a read-only property. Since the code is protected against that, it's obvious that simply binding to the `PropertyInfo` doesn't bind to the property itself.

Comment: Can you show the property implementation?

Comment: Set the Binding's `Path` to a the name of the property, and the `Source` to the object that owns the property.

Answer (score 3):

Set the **`Path`** property of the `Binding` to `prop.Name` and the `Source` property to **`this`** or whatever object that you want to bind to:

```
Binding bind = new Binding() { Path = new PropertyPath(prop.Name), Source = this };
if (prop.CanWrite)
{
    TextBox.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, bind);
}
else
{
    TextBox.IsEnabled = false;
}
```

The `Path` of a `Binding` specifies the property to bind to and the `Source` property specifies the object in which this property is defined.