# Bind properties of a class at runtime (Create ViewModel at runtime)

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, reflection, data-binding

No sure how to present my problem, but I have multiple classes, every class let's say Command51, Command49, Command00 contains multiple properties, what I want to achieve is a way to present to the user a view with multiple textboxes, the number of textboxes are determined by the number of the properties of a class.
For the sake of the example Command51 will have 5 properties, Command49 will have 4 properties and Command00 will have only 1 property:

Let's say I have a textbox where the user can enter a number: 51 or 49 or 00.

As soon as the number is typed under this textbox will appear 5 textboxes if the user entered the number 51 or 4 textboxes if the user entered number 49 and so on.

What I want is to bind these properties to the textboxes dynamically, my main focus is to initialize the class properties via this textboxes.

Class examples:

```
public class Command51 
{
   
    public Command51()
    {

    }

    public byte Prop1 { get; set; }
    public int Prop2 { get; set; }
    public float Prop3 { get; set; }
    public double Prop4 { get; set; }
    public string Prop5 { get; set; }

}

public class Command49 
{
   
    public Command49()
    {

    }

    public byte Prop1 { get; set; }
    public int Prop2 { get; set; }
    public byte Prop3 { get; set; }
    public int Prop4 { get; set; }
}
```

I now that I need to use reflection but not sure how..

```
   <ItemsControl
        VerticalAlignment="Top"
        ItemsSource="{Binding ListOfReflectedSetters}"
        ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type /*DynamicDataType*/}">
                <Grid Margin="5">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock
                        Grid.Column="0"
                        Margin="0,0,5,0"
                        Text="{Binding PropertyName}" />
                    <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding PropertyValue}" />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

Comment: Actually, this post, save my day: [Is it possible to bind to a property using reflection in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41353501/is-it-possible-to-bind-to-a-property-using-reflection-in-wpf)

Answer (score 1):

I put this code on event **TextChanged** of the one **TextBox** you have, which is not efficient so change it as you wish.
You can get **all the classes in your namespace** this way:

```
Type[] AllTypes = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes().Where(t => 
String.Equals(t.Namespace, **YOURNAMESPACENAME**, StringComparison.Ordinal)).ToArray();
```

Then you **loop** through the Types and find the class you want:

```
foreach (Type type in AllTypes)
{
    if (type.Name == TargetClassName)
        {
            //Do Stuff
        }
}
```

For example in your case **//Do Stuff** would be making a number of text boxes, so first we get the number of Properties in that Class:

```
//get number of properties
int PropertyCount = type.GetProperties().Length;
```

Then we make a list of text boxes and add them:

```
//make a list of textboxes for it
List<TextBox> TextBoxes = new List<TextBox>(PropertyCount);

for (int i = 0; i < PropertyCount; i++)
{
    PropertyInfo ThisProperty = type.GetProperties()[i];

    TextBox tb = new TextBox()
    {
        Text = ThisProperty.Name,
        Name = "TB" + i,
        Top = i * 32 + 44,
        Left = 12,
        Height = 20,
        Width = 200,
    };
    //you can add a textchange event here for any of textboxes
    tb.TextChanged += (s, ev) =>
    {
        //Do New Stuff
    };

    TextBoxes.Add(tb);

    Controls.Add(TextBoxes[i]);
}
```

I hope I didn't misunderstand and this answers your question...
This actually my first post here.